# How can I keep my factories stocked with raw materials? Are infinite manual trade runs the answer?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict, x3-albion-prelude

So, I set up a bunch of ships to manually supply my new crystal factory with the needed resources. I did this by ordering several ships to perform infinite manual trade runs.

The problem is that when one of the needed resources is filled to capacity, the ship supplying that resource just gives up on its manual trade run. It does this because it cannot unload all of the resources it is hauling. This in effect cancels the manual trade run order and puts the ship into an idle state.

Instead of being smart about it and waiting until my station uses up enough of the resource to allow the ship to unload its wares, the script just ends and the ship sits idle at the station.

There has to be some way for me to automate the delivery of resources to my station from some (far away) station using one or more of my ships.

It's a pain in the butt to have to sit there and constantly issue manual trade runs, because ships give up so easily when they can't complete the delivery due to not enough space.

Maybe, manual trade runs are not the right order for doing station to station delivery of raw materials?

Please, help!

Answer (score 4):

There are much better ways to supply a station than with the manual trade option.

My preferred method is to download the [X3:AP Bonus Pack](http://www.egosoft.com/download/x3ap/bonus_en.php) which will add the Commercial Agent software into your game.  Note, this will **not** make your game 'modified' so you will still earn achievements.

Once you have the CLS software installed onto your ship, what you'll have to do is to give him a buy order to fill up needed raw materials up to a % point.  If the station has more than that in raw materials it'll simply return home and be on standby until its needed.  Whats even better, you can even have the same ship sell your produced materials as well, reducing the need for multiple ships to service one factory.

Comment: I probably wouldnt have stayed with this game If I hadn't discovered the bonus pack. CLS is a lifesaver when it comes to supply management.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the supply comand software on a ship then go to that ship's comand console and select your crystal fact as home base, then on the trading orders select buy wares at best price and select a resource. This way your ship will refill your station as needed and will never stop.

Comment: That's certainly an option, but commercial agents really are the way to go.